# Create a custom error page to redirect to instead of generic AccessDenied.aspx?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, visual-web-part, access-denied

When a user has not been given permissions to a particular site they receive the ugly "Error: Access Denied" page.

Is it possible to capture this on one particular team site (via custom webpart) and redirect the user to a custom access denied page that displays a more friendlier message (ex: "Thanks for your interest in [my company's team site]. Access has been limited at this time to physicians, fellows, physician extenders, clinical pharmacists, and nurses who are involved in patient care. If you need access for direct patient care and you have received this message, please contact info@mycompany.com".

I found examples using SPSecurity.CatchAccessDeniedException, but it looks like user is being redirected to AccessDenied.aspx before the code gets executed. I placed the code in 
Page_PreRender()

Answer (score 1):

Courtesy of Yaroslav Pentsarsky - [EndUserSharePoint.com](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/devwiki/articles/Pages/Customizing-AccessDenied-SignOut-and-other-pages-in-SharePoint-2010-using-PowerShell.aspx)

1. First you can copy an existing page from the Template/Layouts, in our case we'll use AccessDenied.aspx. You can give it any name. If you’re using a Visual Studio solution simply add this new file to your solution structure underLayouts mapped folder.
2. Make any desired changes to the newly created page. If you made a copy of an existing page, remember that it’s referencing the original assembly and you still need to follow the structure outlined in the page placeholders to avoid the page erroring out. Alternately, you can create your own page in VS2010 which can reference its own assembly.
3. Assuming the page has been deployed to the layouts folder. Execute the following PowerShell to set it as a default page for the role, in our case AccessDenied page role.

   PS C:\Users\Administrator> $site = get-spsite "http://intranet.contoso.com"

   PS C:\Users\Administrator> $webApp = $site.WebApplication

   PS C:\Users\Administrator> $webapp.UpdateMappedPage(1, "/_layouts/AccessDeniedNew.aspx")

   True

   PS C:\Users\Administrator> $webapp.Update()

   PS C:\Users\Administrator>

In here, the value of “1″ in UpdateMappedPage, specifies a reference to an enumeration value for other page roles available, see [SPCustomPage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.spcustompage.aspx) Microsoft reference for more info.

- We’re set. Since we’re testing AccessDenied page, I’m going to log in
  as a reader and access “Site collection administrators” page by URL.s
  a result I am getting my customized AccessDenied page.

**NOTE**: The custom page must always be hosted in _layouts, otherwise the UpdateMappedPage will fail. If you need to show your content page as a result – you can execute a redirect from the custom page in _layouts to your content page.

Comment: If I create an Access Denied message targeting a specific site (with a specific email to contact for any questions) , can I make this work for just this one site? What I mean is...If a user doesnt have access to a different site, I dont want to alter that AccessDenied.aspx message.

Comment: This is an all or nothing thing. It is an .aspx page so you could get fancy with the logic to differentiate.  Another method is to utilize URL rewrite module of IIS and configure some redirect rules to a custom page.  With this you could create a rule that only affects a single site by redirecting from /*site*/_layouts/accessdenied.aspx to another page the user does have access too.

Comment: One more question... I need this for users who do not have access to the main landing page of the site. I created an application page and added an Event Receiver to a feature, but it seems like this does not work. User is ALWAYS redirected to the generic AccessDenied.aspx. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I've tried this, but the powershell script seems not to have any effect.  It still loads the default accessdenied page.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternate you can use DoesUserHavePermissions property of spweb  (SPSecuribleObject) and redirect to another page through code.